# Unexpected Bash completion of ~ on OS X

Tags: bash, users, autocomplete

I pressed <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> on the bash command prompt and got an unexpected set of completions.

First it looked like all the folks in the `/Users` directory, and a lot more.

Then I thought it was doing the reverse lookup of folks with "home" directories in `/etc/password`, or perhaps the ones that were `/var/empty` -- this seems about right.

What I'm curious about is what's *really* going on and *why* this works as it does.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't have an OSX system handy to check on but on all *nixes, `~foo` is a shorthand for the home directory of user `foo`. For example, this command will move into my user's `$HOME` (`cd ~` alone will move into your home directory):

```
cd ~terdon
```

So, `~` and <kbd>Tab</kbd> will expand to all possible user names. The list should be the same as the list of users in `/etc/passwd`.

I can confirm that that is exactly what happens when I try this on my Debian.

Comment: It's the same when I try it on FreeBSD.

Comment: So the thing that threw me was that I didn't have directories in /home for those users.  In fact, many said /var/empty.  I figured that such completions were by disk lookup, so that  ~ would be looking at the actual home directory _on disk_ rather than the /etc/passwd entries.   Because ~ really means "a user's home directory" and not actually a shortcut for /home (or /User), the expansion references /var/empty in my OS X case.  Learned something new! Thanks!

Comment: @WaltStoneburner fdo's answer below suggests that OSX is doing something different, I don't know. On Linux, anyway, creating a directory in `/home` is irrelevant, that won't make a new username be listed. Also, note that not all users' $HOMEs are in `/home` (or `/Users`).

Comment: @terdon - I think you nailed it with your answer.  On my Linux account I have a dovenull user that has a bogus directory of /nonexistent, it shows up in the autocompletion, but the cd command fails (as expected).

Answer (score 2):

> I thought it was doing the reverse lookup of folks with "home" directories in /etc/password.

On OS X Open Directory is consulted instead of /etc/passwd.

Answer (score 1):

Bash Reference Manual [says](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Commands-For-Completion):

> Bash attempts completion treating the text as username (if the text begins with ‘~’)

Bash [uses](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/complete.c#n2166) `getpwent` function for completion.

`man getpwent` on OSX says:

> These functions obtain information from opendirectoryd(8), including
>        records in /etc/master.passwd which is described in master.passwd(5).